# WSL Run Service at Start

Tags: ubuntu, cron, services, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm honestly not sure if this is an issue with WSL or I'm just doing something wrong for Ubuntu in general, but I cannot get the cron service to run at start on my WSL system.

It starts just fine with:

```
sudo service cron start
```

But it doesn't start at boot even after:

```
sudo update-rc.d cron defaults
sudo update-rc.d cron enable
```

Version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux PC-01 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft #476-Microsoft Fri Nov 01 16:53:00 PST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl --failed`?

Comment: @PauloTomé: No systemd on wsl.  Apparently it has it's own microsoft made init system.

Comment: The problem is with WSL. You have to use Windows Task Scheduler, but you can still run a Linux task by scheduling `C:\WSL\Ubuntu\ubuntu1804.exe` with the argument `run /path/to/linux/executable`.

Comment: @bitinerant: Cron does work if I start it manually, I just want some method to start it automatically.

Comment: Maybe https://superuser.com/questions/1343558/how-to-make-wsl-run-services-at-startup could help.

Comment: Maybe you can use the above method to start cron after a Windows reboot.

Comment: @PauloTomé: Thanks, using an rc file did cross my mind but just doesn't seem right.  I guess running linux on windows isn't quite right either though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old question that I just found when searching for a potential "duplicate" for another question that was just asked.  Putting the answer here since this one is the first search result for "wsl start services".

There's a *current* answer and a *future* answer (based on Windows 10/11 Preview versions of WSL currently available).

The current answer is that WSL doesn't have the concept of "startup services".  Microsoft's `init` process is neither a SysVinit nor a Systemd init like on "normal" Linux systems.

If you'd like to start the services automatically, there are *currently* two ways to do it, with a third coming in the next WSL release:

---

- *Option 1:  Set up a Windows "Scheduled Task" to run on login (not boot):*

  - The task can be a "Basic Task" to
  - "Start a Program"
  - The the "Program" is `wsl.exe`
  - And the "Arguments" should be `-u root service cron start`

  That will run WSL at login as the root user (needed to start services) and run the `service cron start` command.  Of course, this can be modified to run any service that has an `init.d` script.  Note that this does not (at least currently) work if you schedule the task to run at Windows Boot, since WSL seems to have a requirement that the user be logged in in order to keep the process running in the background.

---

- *Option 2:  Modify your shell startup to check if the service is running, and start it if needed.*

  In your startup (typically `~/.bashrc`) add the following line:

  ```
  wsl.exe -u root sh -c "service cron status || service cron start"
  ```

  Under "normal" Linux, you'd need to `visudo` and give yourself permission to run the command without a password (or type the password each time you log in).  Using `wsl.exe -u root` from *within* WSL allows you to bypass this.

---

- *Option 3:*  A new feature in Windows 11 is the ability to specify startup tasks for WSL using the `/etc/wsl.conf` file.  If you have Windows 11, create that file with the following lines:

  ```
  [boot]
  command="service cron start"
  ```

  According to the [Microsoft doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#boot-settings), this will run the command as root when the WSL instance starts.

  If you need to run multiple commands at WSL startup, separate them with semicolons in the same `command` line:

  ```
  [boot]
  command="service ssh start; service cron start"
  ```

Comment: Thanks yeah I ended up doing it just with a batch script that runs wsl and starts cron as a windows startup script but nice to know the functionality to do it in a more correct-ish manner is coming.

Answer (score 0):

This post helped my get what I was looking for however I needed to run multiple commands (start xrdp, tweak eth0 mtu, update resolv.conf) and running `wsl.exe` multiple times would instantiate multiple root logins causing some issues with file locking `resolv.conf` possibly because WSL does some setup at each login, not positive.

I am using wsl2 Kernel version: 5.10.102.1 Windows 10 with Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. My needs were

1. Start xrdp (so I can connect to a gui session)
2. Set eth0 mtu to 1350 (WSL had trouble with connectivity while on VPN due to mtu)
3. Update `resolv.conf` with upstream resolvers (kept getting updated by WSL regardless of `generateResolvConf = false` in `wsl.config`)

So to expand on the answer from @NotTheDr01ds here is what I did.

1. Put all commands in a new shell script `.mystartup.sh` in home directory
2. Call `.mystartup.sh` as root from `.profile`

Here is what I added to `.profile`

```
# startup stuff
# run startup script as root
wsl.exe -u root /home/user/.mystartup.sh
```

And here is `.mystartup.sh`

```
# startup stuff
# service xrdp start
service xrdp status || service xrdp start

# setup lower mtu for vpn links
ifconfig eth0 mtu 1350
echo "eth0 mtu updated!"

# remove link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf & create new
rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
touch /etc/resolv.conf
chmod u+rwx,g+rwx,o+rx /etc/resolv.conf

# setup nameservers
echo "# this resolv.conf created using user .profile script" >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo "# wsl auto-generate must be disabled in /etc/wsl.config" >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 10.0.0.50" >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 10.0.0.51" >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo "resolv.conf modified with custom dns resolvers!"
echo
```